# Solr Sorting Not working properly

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I'm using this sample query to group the result set by category:

```
q=test&group=true&group.field=category
```

This works as expected and I get this sample response:

```
"response": 
{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[ 
 { 
  ... 
} 
{"numFound":6,"start":0,"docs":[ 
 { 
  ... 
} 
{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[ 
 { 
  ... 
}
```

However, I can't find a way to specify the sort order of the groups by 
number of docs each group has ("numFound field). I think the "sort" param 
has something to do with it, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems silly, but there may not be an easy way. One [solr-user maillist thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/solr-user@lucene.apache.org/msg56366.html) says no. There's another thread I found that it may be doable with a [local params and nested query](http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/13270kxp1x/sorting-grouped-results-by-numfound). Basically, seems like there is no easy way to do this.

One possible approach if you have a lot of groups, is to do one query where the `group.limit=0`, do the sorting in the app, then use the `fq` parameter to filter on just those values.

[This page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) seems like a pretty good general reference on all the grouping functions.